# Chrome on Android 10 image uploading strips GPS EXIF Data

Tags: android, google-chrome, gps, exif

I have a very simple ASP.net web page that I am using to upload images from mobile devices. It would seem that a recent update of Chrome on Android 10, primarily on Samsung phones is stripping the GPS component of the EXIF data from the images when uploading to a website. All photos are properly geotagged on the phone just fine and I can use Firefox or Edge on the phone to upload photos and successfully retrieve the GPS data. My question is does anyone know a way around this with Chrome, since it is the preferred browser on Androids. I have been unable to find anything about this yet.

I am simply using:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-upload">
```

If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Safari on iOS does the same thing. It seems it is the same trend that updated platforms are taking into consideration to provide more safety and privacy for users.

Comment: Dang. Why?  Do you think that if the page requests location access it could fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `accept="image/*`, android will use a different native menu. Images selected from the quick preview will replace the GPS info as NaN.

`<input type="file" id="file-upload">`

Comment: I just tried this and it does work