# When uploading an image via a PWA (Android 10 / Chrome 92.0), the Exif GPS data is stripped

Tags: android, google-chrome, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, exif

I have developed a PWA through which, among other things, images are transferred to a database.

Until recently everything worked fine, but since the last Android and/or Chrome update the GPS data of the images are removed from their Exif data.
Is there any way to disable this new behavior of Chrome / Android? The browser has rights to both the camera and the location.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is a PWA ?

Comment: A progressive web app. (A web application with offline features that behaves almost like a native app).

Comment: This one works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171191/4443235